# R: Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") :

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have a dataset arranged like below: 6 columns 6 rows. I am trying to view gene expression between tumour(TCGA) and normal(GTEX).

| primary.disease | study | gene1 | gene2 | gene3 | gene4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LUAD | TCGA | 6.4 | 8.9 | 2.3 | 7.9 |
| LUAD | TCGA | 7.8 | 7.9 | 1.0 | 9.3 |
| LUAD | TCGA | 8.0 | 8.8 | 0.6 | 9.2 |
| LUSC | TCGA | 6.9 | 6.7 | 0 | 8.5 |
| LUNG | GTEX | 7.1 | 2.1 | 5.5 | 1.1 |
| LUNG | GTEX | 7.4 | 1.3 | 4.8 | 4.6 |

For this dataset i want to to test whether the mean of each gene (columns) are different between TCGA and GTEX. i want the function to compare TCGA values to GTEX values for each genes. I used the apply function and did this code to find p value for all columns:

```r
GEPVals <- apply(TCGA_GTEX_lung[-2],2,function(x) t.test(x[1:4],x[5:6])$p.value)
```

However got this error:

Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") :

missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In var(y) :

What am i doing wrong and how should i correct these code?